# Google Captcha in registration form verify.php issue

Tags: php, forms, registration, captcha

I used google captcha in my site registration form as google example:

```
  <form method="post" action="htt://mysite/folder/verify.php">
    <?php
      require_once('htt://mysite/folder/recaptchalib.php');
      $publickey = "your_public_key"; // you got this from the signup page
      echo recaptcha_get_html($publickey);
    ?>
    <input type="submit" />
  </form>

  <!-- more of your HTML content -->
</body>
```

in the verify.php this code

```
<?php
require_once('htt://mysite/folder/recaptchalib.php');
$privatekey = "your_private_key";
$resp = recaptcha_check_answer ($privatekey,
                            $_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"],
                            $_POST["recaptcha_challenge_field"],
                            $_POST["recaptcha_response_field"]);

if (!$resp->is_valid) {
// What happens when the CAPTCHA was entered incorrectly
die ("The reCAPTCHA wasn't entered correctly. Go back and try it again." .
     "(reCAPTCHA said: " . $resp->error . ")");
} else {
// Your code here to handle a successful verification
}
?>
```

everything works fine, the captcha finds out the correct/wrong captcha combination but when i click the submit button it shows a blank page with URL htt://mysite/folder/very.php
It should continue to the email verification but it doesn't..

Answer (score 0):

Could you please show us your code? Actually, if it goes in the right statement `(if || else)`, the problem is in the part of the code which you don't post.

Seems like an error has occurred in your mail sending method.